# When sending data, why does System.Net.Http.StreamContent read the whole stream into memory, ignoring the given buffer size?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

The following code reads the whole given `Stream`'s data into memory before sending it as a web request rather than reading and sending the data in smaller blocks. For example, if the stream yields 2 GB of data, the code will read all the 2 GB of data into a memory buffer before it starts sending the request. The 50 KB buffer size passed to `StreamContent`'s constructor seem to be ignored.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
  using (var content = new StreamContent(stream, 1024*50)) // 50 KB buffer size ignored?
  {
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri))
    {
      request.Content = content;
      await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @canton7 I think `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` is about _receiving_ large data using `HttpClient`, right? I'm talking about _sending_ large data using `HttpClient`.

Comment: @canton7 I've reworded the question to make this clearer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: If possible try to avoid to use HttpClient like this way. Please read this [in-depth article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-creation-and-disposal-internals-should-i-dispose-of-httpclient) to better understand the consequences of disposing HttpClients.

Comment: And there is this [old but gold article](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) as well.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the given `Stream` does not support seeking. In that case, the `StreamContent` cannot use the `Stream.Length` property to retrieve its size, which is required to construct the HTTP request message.

However, if you specify that the "[chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)" should be used, it works. That way, the content can be sent in chunks without having to determine its size up-front.

So, this code will avoid loading the whole data into memory even if it doesn't allow seeking:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
  using (var content = new StreamContent(stream, 1024*50))
  {
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri))
    {
      request.Content = content;

      // Enable the request message to be sent without knowing the final content size
      request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
      
      await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
  }
}
```